# git reordering commits with conflicts

Tags: git

Assume I have two commits, the first (older) commit introduces a function call and the second (younger) commit adds parameters to the function. See the example below.

Now I see the function name was misleading. I create a third commit that changes the function name but I want to have it changed in the first one too.

**I know and understand why I can't rebase, reorder and squash the commits**
but what would be a viable way to solve this?

#### What it is like

Last:

```
function_reasonable_name(parameters);
```

Second:

```
function_misleading_name(parameters);
```

First:

```
function_misleading_name();
```

#### What it should be

Second:

```
function_reasonable_name(parameters);
```

First:

```
function_reasonable_name();
```

All commits are not pushed, correcting this does no harm. I simply have no idea how to do that with least effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best handled using interactive rebase. First, do a `rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD master)`, and select "edit" instead of "pick" for your first commit. Git will then apply your commit, and then stop, letting you amend it. Change the name of the function, amend the commit, and resume the rebasing via `git rebase --continue`. Your second commit will then be in conflict with the first, so git will stop the rebasing to let you resolve the conflict. When done, resume the rebase again using `git rebase --continue`. The third commit will then be empty, and should get skipped by git. You should now have two commits, both using the correct name for the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve what you describe without manually constructing the source tree you want in the new intermediate commit. There'll be little automation to help you since Git's conflict resolution strategies are (as far as I know) strictly line-granular.

The procedure would be something like

1. name the original "last" commit as a temporary branch
2. In your working branch `git reset --hard` back to the "first" commit.
3. Refactor the code to change the name to `function_reasonable_name`.
4. `git commit --amend .` to create the *first* new commit.
5. `git checkout TEMP_BRANCH_NAME -- .`

   This stages the changes to make the code tree identical to the final state you started with.
6. `git commit`

   Copy the commit comment by hand.

---

If you have intermediate commits that you don't speak about in the question, it might be worth trying an *interactive rebase* (which will need some manual conflict resolution at several points) instead to get new intermediate commits made.